# Entering Values into NumericUpDown with unit

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I have declared a control deriving from NumericUpDown to display a unit in the text area:

```
    public class NumericUpDownUnit : NumericUpDown
{
    public string Unit { get; set; } = "";
    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        Text = Value.ToString("N" + DecimalPlaces) + " " + Unit;
    }
}
```

It works fine, but when I try to edit that value (e. g. "250 kg") as the application is running, it won't take it before I remove the unit from the text, because of course it's not a valid number.

How can I extend my control to take the new value?

Comment: You could have the `OnEnter` event remove the 'N' and then `OnExit` put it back.

Comment: Just for info, this is poor UX design to leave the unit inside the input field, except if the unit is significant and editable; but even then, I'd rather have a second separate input for it.